# Javascript - Mocha Chai Unit Test. Test is not running

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am working on a project with a Front End Web Development Course bootcamp and our professors unfortunately were not able to answer this question that I had.

I have a simple card game of War that will ask for two players and then play out the 26 turns and see who wins. Within this game I have 4 classes which are the following

- Card
- Deck
- Player
- War

These are all set as modules so that they may be exported and then imported to all the corresponding JS files that require them to run.

Then I have a set of unit testing files which then will attempt to use each of the corresponding files and then generate tests to tests.html

This will access each corresponding unit test js file and then run through the describe methods. however, they will not actually run the corresponding "it" functions for the unit test (This is verified by console.log() within the describe and the it functions. When I attempt to go to the console on the web browser it also does not throw any errors to debug with.

This first link is my master branch of what I had turned in for week 6, you will see that the tests work when I do not import, and then have the corresponding classes in the describe.
https://github.com/jeffhennen/Projects/tree/master/Week6/Week6Final

I want this to use the live code from the files and not the unit tests while also having each of these corresponding files seperated out like I have it within this section.
https://github.com/jeffhennen/Projects/tree/Test/Week6/Week6Final

This is my tests.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "mocha"><p><a href=".">Index</a></p></div>
    <div id = "messages"></div>
    <div id = "fixtures"></div>
    <script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/Card.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/Deck.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/Player.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/War.js"></script>
    <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
    <script type="module" src="UnitTests/CardTest.js"></script> 
    <script type="module" src="UnitTests/DeckTest.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="UnitTests/PlayerTest.js"></script>
    <script>mocha.run();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the example of my CardTest.js file

```
var expect = chai.expect;
import Card from '../Scripts/Card.js';

describe('Card Functions', () => {

    describe('Constructor', () => {

        console.log("Inside card describe constructor");
        let card = new Card("Club", "King", 13);
        console.log(card);
        it('Should create the card with the value of the card\'s suit equal to param 0', () => {

            console.log("test1");
            expect(card._suit).to.equal("Club");
        });

        it('Should create the card with the value of the card\'s string value equal to the param 1', () => {

            console.log("test2");
            expect(card._number).to.equal("King");
        });

        it('Should assign the numeric value of the card\'s string value to the card object', () => {

            console.log("test3");
            expect(card._value).to.equal(13);
        });
    });
});
```

This is my Card.js file

```
class Card{

    constructor(suit, number, value){

        this._suit = suit;
        this._value = value;
        this._number = number;
    }

    get suit(){

        return this._suit;
    }

    get value(){

        return this._value;
    }

    get number(){

        return this._number;
    }
    
}
export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found out that all I needed to do to get this running is to update the tests.html to the following where i just needed to update the  tag to

```
<script type="module">
       mocha.run();
</script>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "mocha"><p><a href=".">Index</a></p></div>
    <div id = "messages"></div>
    <div id = "fixtures"></div>
    <script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/Card.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/Deck.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/Player.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/War.js"></script>
    <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
    <script type="module" src="UnitTests/CardTest.js"></script> 
    <script type="module" src="UnitTests/DeckTest.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="UnitTests/PlayerTest.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
       mocha.run();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```